# Is "bring sth/sb up to do sth" grammatically correct & often used?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

I came across a phrase like this in a news article some time ago:

> I bring myself up to kiss her.

I want to ask about the grammatical correctness of the sentence and the frequency of the phrase/phrasal verb "bring sb/sth up to do sth"

Comment: Please use "something" rather than shortening it.  Also, please could you add more context to the quoted section?

Comment: To me, _bring someone up to do something_ means _rear your child to habitually behave in a certain way_.

Comment: Alternatively, it could mean to have someone physically upwards to do something -- "we brought him up on the stage to receive the award" -- but that's not something you can normally do to yourself.